# Redirect Login to Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity-3

Starting with the ASP.NET 5 Web App Template using Individual User Accounts I have managed to get external authentication working with Microsoft accounts. When users click Login they are redirected to `ExternalLogin` in `AccountController` like this

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="ExternalLogin" method="post" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" class="nav navbar-right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-null nav navbar-nav navbar-right" name="provider" value="Microsoft" title="Log in"><span class="fa fa-sign-in"/>&nbsp; Log In</button>
</form>
```

That gets them logged in using thier Microsoft account and all seems to work nicely. But how do I intercept direct attempts to access privileged actions `[Authorize]`
 so that the user is redirected to `ExternalLogin`? Can a default action be set in `Startup.cs`?

**EDIT 1** Attempting to follow the advice of @Yves I have created `CustomAutorizationFilter` in a Filters folder. It doesn't check for any conditions

```
public class CustomAutorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        //if (...) // Check you conditions here
        //{
            context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("ExternalLogin", "Account", null);
        //}
    }
}
```

and have edited `ConfigureServices` as below

```
        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            config.Filters.Add(typeof(Filters.CustomAutorizationFilter));
        });
```

When I run the app locally it no longer goes to the Home page. It returns a blank `http://localhost:52711/Account/ExternalLogin`

Obviously there is much I do not understand.

**Edit 2:** Here is the signature of `ExternalLogin`

```
 // POST: /Account/ExternalLogin
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
```

This is how `ExternalLogin` comes out of the box in the ASP.Net 5 Web App Template.

Comment: I guess there may be a redirect loop after your edit. Try to add `AllowAnonymousAttribute` to your `ExternalLogin` controller. If I'm not mistaken that attribute bypasses `IAuthorizationFilter`. You can debug it to see what is happening. I'm not on a pc ATM. So I can't check it.

Comment: I have added the signature of `ExternalLogin` to my question.

Comment: @Yves is correct about the redirect loop. It keep looping through `context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("ExternalLogin", "Account", null);` Without ever hitting `ExternalLogin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I was unable to get `CustomAuthorizationFilter` working as suggested by @Yves I have resorted to a nasty hack. I have modified `AccountController Login` as below

```
     // GET: /Account/Login
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(ExternalLogin), new { provider = "Microsoft", returnUrl = returnUrl });
        //return View();
    }
```

This seems to work but I'd appreciate any feedback or advice if there is a better way.

Answer (score 3):

You can register an `IAuthorizationFilter` or an `IActionFilter` implementations to accomplish this. In these filters you can check if the request is trying to access a privileged action, if the user is logged in or have enough permission to do it.

If you are using `AutorizeAttribute`, I suggest you to use `AutorizationFilter`.
If you go with your own custom attributes, then use `ActionFilter`.

Here is an example:

MVC calls `IAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization` method before every action execution.

```
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        if (...) // Check you conditions here
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("ExternalLogin", "Account", null);
        }
    }
}
```

To register this filter, in Startup.cs edit your `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    config.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomAuthorizationFilter ));
});
```

Or if you wan to use your own attributes you can use `ActionFilter`'s `OnActionExecuting` method to check if everything is happening as you wish...

Comment: Thank you @Yves. What conditions are checked? Are you talking about something like `if(!user.IsAuthorized)` or do you mean something else? Our setup is pretty simple; I just want to know if they are logged in or if they are in the Admins role.

Comment: If you just want to redirect unlogged in users then `IsAuthorized` is enough I think. This is really depend on your business logic ;)

Comment: Thank you again @Yves. I am still not getting the result I hope for. I have edited my question to include my attempt to follow your advice.

Comment: If you use `IAuthorizationFilter`, please implement `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` too, I had problems with it