# .Net Core MVC Custom Login Screen

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I am looking to create a custom login screen. I have a static LDAP based user authorization class that I want to authenticate whenever any view in my application is accessed if the user is not logged in.

I found some information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization) on authorization but the part I am lost on is returning the login view when the user is not authenticated.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie) also looks like it might be what I am looking for but I have some questions like, does this work by configuring it as shown on the MSDN and slapping the [Authorize] attribute on the controller views you want authenticated?

Basically, how can I boil the authentication down to:

```
Authenticated
    |
    |--->Yes: Return Called View
    |
    |--->No: Return Login Page -> validate vs LDAPAuth.Validate(Username, Password)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969144/redirect-login-to-controller-action This ended up answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

Authentication and authorization are two separate items.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity is what you want, look at the loginpath attribute.